# how to use the theme of TabBar?

Tags: flutter, themes

i created a theme for TabBar, **which is**:

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppWidget();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black, // and so on
              ),),
          home: const HomePage(),
        );},);}
}
```

when i use TabBar the is no implementation of the theme, which i have been created. How can i use the TabBar theme above inside TabBar implementation?

**the code of TabBar is:**

```
class HomeCustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: AppBar(
        // how to get the TabBar Theme here?
        bottom:TabBar([]),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(140);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should not need to use directly the `TabBarTheme` it should be applied automatically to all TabBar's after setting in in the ThemeData. Nevertheless if you still wish to access it you can by just using :

```
TabBarTheme.of(context)
```